# Tab autocompletion and history in tcsh

Tags: command-history, autocomplete, tcsh

I use tcsh, and I'd like to set up the following behaviour, which I've seen on some systems in the past. If I type

```
!string TAB
```

then:

- If the history contains a unique entry beginning with `string`, autocompletion should take place, and I can edit the resulting command, or just press return to execute it.
- If the history contains multiple entries beginning with `string`, a list of possible completions is displayed, the command is partially completed as far as possible (without eliminating any possibilities from the list), and on the command line I should have an exclamation mark followed by the partially completed command, so that I can type more characters and press TAB again.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
set autoexpand
```

to `.tcshrc` to activate this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are searching for `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` editor commands.

As default, these commands are binded to **M-p** (usually <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on pc keyboards) and **M-n** (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>).

You can re-bind them to any other key sequence using `bindkey` command. E.g.:

```
 bindkey '\t' history-search-backward
```

Note that you do not need to place a `!` at line beginning to use these commands.

Comment: No, that's something different.

Comment: @infoclogged thank you, I fixed the typo in the example